# ¿Cómo se consigue más allá de los primeros 200 followers por la API de Twitter?

Tags: php, api, twitter

Solo consigo acceder al máximo de 200 usuarios que te da Twitter de la primera página por la API.

Intento usar el cursor, per el siguiente y el anterior siempre me da 0, aunque coja la lista de un usuario con 200K seguidores.

Este es el código que uso:

```
do{
        $json =  $twitter->setGetfield($getfield.'&cursor='.$cursor)
            ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->performRequest();
        $json = json_decode($json); 
        $friends[] = $json->users;
        $cursor = $json->next_cursor;  
        echo $cursor; 
        $j++;
} while(($cursor)!=0);
```

El metodo es 'GET'.

La `$url` es:

```
'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json'
```

Y `$getfield` contiene lo siguiente:

```
'?screen_name='.$screen_name.'&count=200'
```

Comment: ¿No tengo ni idea eh, pero podría ser por el `count=200`?

Comment: Es el máximo que te deja recoger twitter por página, para ir a las siguientes paginas tienes que usar el cursor. El problema es que el cursor siguiente me da cero

Comment: Es muy raro lo que te pasa. ¿Qué valor le pasas a `$cursor` inicialmente? ¿Será que llegaste al límite de peticiones diarias?

Comment: No, acabo de hacerlo solo llevo hoy tres o cuatro como  máximo, inicio con el cursor en -1

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como comenta la documentación oficial en [Follow, search, and get users](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list) para el parámetro `cursor`:

> Causes the results to be broken into pages. If no cursor is provided, a value of -1 will be assumed, which is the first “page.”
>
> The response from the API will include a previous_cursor and next_cursor to allow paging back and forth. See [Using cursors to navigate collections](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/cursoring) for more information.

Es decir, que para cada resultado de una llamada debes recoger el valor de `next_cursor` e inyectarlo en la siguiente iteración.

Y en la parte enlazada dice:

> The `next_cursor` is the cursor that you should send to the endpoint to receive the next batch of responses, and the `previous_cursor` is the cursor that you should send to receive the previous batch. You will know that you have requested the last available page of results when the API responds with a `next_cursor = 0`.

Como ves, además, el valor por defecto es -1 y corresponde a la primera página. A partir de allí, `next_cursor` valdrá cosas como "1489467234237774933" hasta que devuelva 0 cuando haya llegado al final.

Comment: Eso es, pero solo consiigo la primera página, inicio el cursor en -1 (que es la primera), y solo consigo esa porque luego la siguiente no tiene nada, y he probado con el usuario de twitter @norcoreano que tiene miles y miles de seguidores, aún así no lo consigo

Comment: Estoy intentando probar el código pero no consigo obtener un OAuth token :/

Comment: ¿Qué módulo utilizas para conectar a Twitter? Esto es, ¿cómo defines el objeto `$twitter`?

Comment: Si lo hago de la siguiente forma:

 $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($this->settings);

Uso la TwitterAPIExchange.

Y los token y demás lo hago con el siguiente constructor:

    public function __construct($token,$token_secret,$consumer_key,$consumer_secret) {                
        $this->settings = array(
                   'oauth_access_token' => $token,
                   'oauth_access_token_secret' => $token_secret,
                   'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                   'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret
                );
    }

Comment: Ah exacto, usando https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php. Yo también lo intento así pero no consigo generar el OAuth a través de https://apps.twitter.com/app/ y luego en "Keys and access tokens". Allí obtengo Consumer Key (API Key), Consumer Secret (API Secret), Access Token y Access Token Secret. Estos dos últimos asumo que son el OAuth, pero al ponerlos me da error 32 "could not authenticate you".

Comment: Qué extraño... yo no he tenido problema con eso. Supongo que te has registrado y has creado la aplicación no?? Seguro que sí.
Prueba a regenerar los token y ponlos de nuevo